# How to access a deeply nested key inside a request.get().json() response?

Tags: python

im trying to request the item availability for this product and I've managed to request the Json string, which allows me to see the item availability but I wanted to parse the rest of the json string except that certain piece of the string. Im pretty new to python but heres what I got so far

```
    #Load Vars -- Note the Headers Wont Be Static I have to change them with a lib
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

url = ('https://target.com')
#Ping the site to see if its up and we arent blocked 200 means good 400 means bad LOL 

response = requests.get( url, headers=headers)

print(response)

#Load Product XHR URL

xhrURL = ("https://redsky.target.com/redsky_aggregations/v1/web/pdp_fulfillment_v1?key=ff457966e64d5e877fdbad070f276d18ecec4a01&tcin=81114595&store_id=1843&store_positions_store_id=1843&has_store_positions_store_id=true&zip=92506&state=CA&latitude=33.959917&longitude=-117.405621&scheduled_delivery_store_id=291&pricing_store_id=1843")

jsonData = requests.get(xhrURL).json()

print(jsonData)
```

It returns with

```
    {'data': {'product': {'__typename': 'Product', 'tcin': '81114595', 'notify_me_enabled': False, 'store_positions': [{'aisle': 41, 'block': 'E'}, {'aisle': 40, 'block': 'E'}], 'fulfillment': {'product_id': '81114595', 'is_out_of_stock_in_all_store_locations': True, 'store_options': [{'location_name': 'Riverside SE', 'location_address': '2755 Canyon Springs Pkwy,Riverside,CA,92507-0932', 'location_id': '1843', 'search_response_store_type': 'PRIMARY', 'location_available_to_promise_quantity': 0.0, 'order_pickup': {'availability_status': 'OUT_OF_STOCK', 'reason_code': 'OUT_OF_STOCK'}, 'in_store_only': {'availability_status': 'OUT_OF_STOCK'}, 'ship_to_store': {'availability_status': 'UNAVAILABLE'}}], 'shipping_options': {'availability_status': 'OUT_OF_STOCK', 'loyalty_availability_status': 'OUT_OF_STOCK', 'available_to_promise_quantity': 0.0, 'reason_code': 'INVENTORY_UNAVAILABLE', 'minimum_order_quantity': 1.0, 'services': []}, 'scheduled_delivery': {'availability_status': 'UNAVAILABLE'}}}}}
```

which is good but I want to parse it even further and only print out the "avalibility status"

Any input as all is appreciated

Best- armando

Comment: `requests.get(xhrURL).json()` returns a python representation of the json: an object would be a dictionary an array a list etc., you just need to access the value by using the correct keys.

Comment: It is a dictionary - you access its data as with any other dictionary. There are at least 5 keys of `'availability_status'` in the data you've shown, there might be more it more then 1 shop_options is returned (it is a list, so there might be multiple shops. It is unclear which of the **5** `'availability_status'` you want. Also you might want to check `json_data["data"]["product"]["fulfillment"]["is_out_of_stock_in_all_store_locations"]` for a quick peek if its not avaiable at all

Answer (score -1):

This way you can access the availability inside of `jsonData`

```
print(jsonData['data']['product']['fulfillment']['shipping_options']['availability_status'])
```

Comment: There are at least 5 keys of `'availability_status'` in the response - also possible multiple stores could be returned in the store_options